# Adding 10/100 router to a gigabit router to handle non-gigabit devices

Tags: networking, router, gigabit-ethernet

I have a wireless router with Gigabit LAN. My Desktop, NAS and laptop have a gigabit LAN. All are currently communicating at a gigabit speed. However, my gigabit router has only 4 ports. I need to add 3 CCTV devices to my network and I have some 10/100 old router lying around and was thinking of bridging my old 10/100 router to my gigabit router to add more slots. My question is: will my DESKTOP-NAS-LAPTOP communication slow down even if all these "main" devices are connected to the gigabit router while the CCTVs are only on 10/100 router?

See network diagram:
[image: Network Diagram]

Comment: It won't slow down GbE-to-GbE connections, but you'll want to make sure you're connecting a *switch*, not an additional *router*. (it's possible to configure most consumer routers in a switch-like mode)

Comment: Thanks bob! Hopefully I can configure my old router to switch like mode. Worst case will just get a gigabit switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you mix gigabit and 10/100 ethernet on the same network?](https://superuser.com/questions/281558/can-you-mix-gigabit-and-10-100-ethernet-on-the-same-network)

Comment: For the most part, unless the router has an explicit switch mode (which bridges the WAN port), you should simply pretend the WAN port does not exist, disable the DHCP server on the router (to avoid clashes), and connect devices (including the upstream router) via the LAN ports. In consumer routers, the LAN ports act as a switch between themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely dependent on your hardware, but if both of your routers were manufactured in the last decade, they should act as a [network switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) for local network packets on the same subnet, without any settings being changed.  From your diagram, it looks like that is what you have.

The Gigabit network ports will automatically detect the lower speed port of the 2nd router on the other end, and will have a buffer that allows packets to be stored before being sent over the wire. The other direction shouldn't be a problem, as it can only send at 1/10 of available bandwidth.

This is in fact the setup I have, with my Gigabit Linksys EA6200 in my office, and my Linksys EA6100, in bridged mode, handling the family's phones, gaming consoles and multimedia devices. Since I've done that I haven't had any problems that weren't upstream.

Your CCTV is most likely going to only need around 3Mbps each, unless you're doing High Def. Here's a [handy calculator](http://www.stardot.com/bandwidth-and-storage-calculator) to figure out what you're in for as far as bandwidth and storage.

So I doubt you're going to notice any slowdown of network traffic.  However, you might notice some contention on the NAS if you are streaming your CCTV to that.

Comment: The LAN ports *are* usually switched, *but* most consumer routers have a DHCP server enabled by default. Having two DHCP servers on the same broadcast domain is a bad idea (TM). So, no, you generally cannot do this "without any settings being changed".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each port can negotiate the fastest speed it can support, either gigabit or 100Mb speed.  The CCTVs will just be throttled to a total speed of 100Mb/s

Like others have commented, your diagram has 2 routers. If you don't have this 10/100 router in bridge mode, you need to make sure it is configured to use the gigabit router as its default gateway.  You potentially also need to handle the routing between the CCTV network and the LAN with a route added to the gigabit router (or use NAT)

EDIT: fixed wording