# Connecting GigabitEthernet port to FastEthernet, no speed reduce?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, gigabit-ethernet

I was reading [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/281558/can-you-mix-gigabit-and-10-100-ethernet-on-the-same-network). The top answer said:

> Gigabit or 100Mbit (or 10Mbit) will be decided on a link-by-link basis, and it is possible to mix the two within a network. Each router/switch should automatically negotiate the fastest link speed (although sometimes it's better to specify this manually, if possible).
> So, it makes sense to group all 100Mbit hardware with your existing 100Mbit switch; likewise for the Gigabit hardware and router. It will not slow down the Gigabit section of the network.

I didn't understand it correctly, suppose **this example**:
First, suppose that FastEthernet speed is 10mbps and GigabitEthernet speed is 1000mbps.

Time 0:0:0-> PC1 has only one FastEthernet port and PC2 has only a GigabitEthernet port.
Time 0:0:1-> PC1 is now connected to PC2 and PC1 wants to send a 1000 megabit file.
Time 0:0:2-> PC1 sends 10 megabit to PC2.PC2 now having 10 megabits of the file.
Time 0:0:3-> PC1 sends 10 megabit to PC2.PC2 now has 20 megabits of the file.

Let's calculate the **speed** for each one:
PC1 has sent 20 megabits in 2 seconds. So the speed of PC1 is 10 Mbps.
PC2 has received 20 megabits in 2 seconds. So the speed of PC2 is 10 Mbps.

My (maybe wrong) **conclusion**:
Both speeds were reduced to the minimum one.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, both directions will be reduced to the minimum speed. This however applies to each link separately. Each cable between any two devices is a link.

Imagine having following setup:

- PC1, PC2 with 10 Mbps
- PC3, Switch1 with 1000 Mbps
- Link1 between PC1 and Switch1 - negotiated to highest common speed, 10 Mbps both ways
- Link2 between PC2 and Switch1 - negotiated to 10 Mbps
- Link3 between PC3 and Switch1 - negotiated to 1000 Mbps

Then if you send file from PC3 to PC1, the data will go through Link3 and Link1. Speed will be limited to 10 Mbps only, because it is the lowest speed along the path. Link3 will however not be saturated and you could simultaneously send an additional file from PC3 to PC2 (also limited to 10 Mbps).

The author of the mentioned question is however asking, if he connects additional Switch2 (with 100 Mbps) to Switch1, whether it will cause Switch1 to drop down to 100 Mbps. No, it will only cause the link between the two of them to be 100 Mbps, Link3 will remain 1000 Mbps and it will not affect speeds on that part of the network.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> First, suppose that FastEthernet speed is 10mbps and GigabitEthernet speed is 1000mbps.

"Fast Ethernet" means 100 Mbps.

(10 Mbps is regular, original Ethernet.)

> Time 0:0:0-> PC1 has only one FastEthernet port and PC2 has only a GigabitEthernet port.

The ports will perform [autonegotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation) (announce each other's capabilities), find the fastest mode that they have *in common,* and will establish a 100 Mbps "Fast Ethernet" link. The link speed will be identical in both directions (i.e. both PC1 *and* PC2 will transmit at 100 Mbps).

> > So, it makes sense to group all 100Mbit hardware with your existing 100Mbit switch; likewise for the Gigabit hardware and router. It will not slow down the Gigabit section of the network.

It's true that 100Mbit hardware will be fine using a 100Mbit switch in general, but that switch's *uplink* port(s) may become the bottleneck if it's only 100Mbit as well. There is a middle ground – switches with lots of 100Mbit downlink ports but also a few 1Gbit uplink ports (e.g. 48×Fast+2×Gbit).

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I'm reading ...but my reference for 10 Mbps is https://www.comnet.net/about/news/fast-ethernet-vs-gagabit-ethernet#:~:text=A%20Fast%20Ethernet%20switch%20can,than%20a%20Fast%20Ethernet%20switch.

Comment: That page says 100 Mbps.

Comment: A Fast Ethernet switch can transfer data packets at a rate of 10 megabits per second. A Gigabit Ethernet switch transfers data packets at relatively higher speeds of one gigabit per second.

In comparison, a Gigabit Ethernet switch can transfer data packets at around 100 times faster than a Fast Ethernet switch.

Comment: This is the actual text. Would you please check the page again?

Comment: The same page also says "Fast Ethernet provided uniform operability for data transmission at over 100 megabits per second". It also says "Fast Ethernet transmission is at least 10 times faster than standard Ethernet" (and standard Ethernet was 10 Mbps, thus Fast Ethernet must be 100 Mbps). In other words, the page directly contradicts itself.